# How to update MS Access Database with a parameter (from VB.NET)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am in the process of creating a program where I am trying to update an Access database with a parameter. However, it keeps failing for some reason.
When I try to replace my varying parameter with a literal string everything seems to work fine and my database is getting updated.

```
Dim connectionString As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source={DatabaseFilePath};"

        'Construct an SQL Statement
        Dim updateSql2 As String = "UPDATE JobDetails Set Project = @Project WHERE [Quote Number] = @QuoteNumber "


        Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(updateSql2, connection)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuoteNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = QuoteNumber
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = ProjectName

                'cmd.Parameters.Add("@RevisionNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = RevisionNo

                'Execute the query
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer
                Try
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try


                If rowsAffected > 0 Then
                    ' The update was successful
                    MessageBox.Show("Data updated successfully.")
                Else
                    ' No rows were affected, meaning no matching record was found
                    MessageBox.Show("No matching record found for the specified quote number and revision number.")
                End If
            End Using

        End Using
```

Above is my code.

When I replace @QuoteNumber with an actual number from the database (ex: '12345'), and @Project with a a literal string 'ProjectA', that works fine.

However, when I try to replace just the @QuoteNumber with '12345', and leave the other Project variable as @Project, the result is that my Project column gets updated with '12345'.

Finally, when I try to leave @QuoteNumber and @Project as is, nothing happens.

What am I missing? I am relatively new to Access & SQL and this is my first program trying to use SQL.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure you use the same name within the query as you do the parameter add. In this case you have project and projectName. not the same thing.

Comment: You added the parameters in the wrong order. See [OleDb.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap these two lines around

> cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuoteNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = QuoteNumber
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = ProjectName

becomes

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = ProjectName
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuoteNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = QuoteNumber
```

When using the OleDb driver, it uses Parameter order instead of Names